# Verifying a proof for the existence of $n$th roots

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove Theorem 1.21 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, which basically states

> For each $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique $y\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $y^n=x$.

---

The exposition of my proof is essentially the same as Rudin's, where I show that the supremum of $S:= \{s\in \mathbb{R}: s^n\leq x\}$ exists. We need to show $(\sup S)^n=x$, from which we assume for the sake of contradiction $(\sup S)^n<x$ or $(\sup S)^n>x$. I am attempting a proof that avoids the approximations made in the book's proof, but I am not sure if my idea is valid.

Suppose that $(\sup S)^n<x$. Then consider the set $T:= \{t\in \mathbb{R}:t^n < x/(\sup S)^n\}$. Note that $T$ is non-empty; $(\sup S)^n<x$ implies $1<x/(\sup S)^n$, and since $1^n=1$, we know $1\in T$. Furthermore, $T$ is bounded above; if $t\in T$ and $t>1$, then $t<t^n<x/(\sup S)^n$. If $t<1$, then $t<1<x/(\sup S)^n$. By the least upper bound property, we know $\sup T$ exists.

In the same way that we assumed $(\sup S)^n<x$, we must also have $(\sup T)^n<x/(\sup S)^n$ (this is the step that I am not confident about).
Note that $1\in T$ means $1<\sup T$, which implies
\begin{align*}
1 &< (\sup T)^n < \frac{x}{(\sup S)^n},\\
(\sup S)^n &< (\sup S\cdot \sup T)^n<x.
\end{align*}
We have shown that $\sup S\cdot \sup T\in S$, which means $\sup S$ is not the least upper bound of S. The proof for the case $(\sup S)^n>x$ follows similarly.

I would like to know if I can assume $(\sup T)^n<x/(\sup S)^n$ just as I assumed $(\sup S)^n<x$. My reasoning is that $(\sup S)^n<x$ is general enough assumption that other similarly constructed sets must also have this property. I would also like to know if my approach can be salvaged if that assumption is invalid.

Comment: You should probably say $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$, otherwise for even $n$ you'll have two real roots.

Comment: I believe your idea is valid, but a lot of your strict inequalities need to be replaced by non-strict ones. On the step you are unsure about, you do not have a guarantee $(\sup T)^n < x/(\sup S)^n$, but you do have $\le$ (you should include an explanation of why in your proof). Similarly, you don't have $\sup T > 1$, only $\sup T \ge 1$.

Comment: You cannot assume $(\sup T)^n < x/(\sup S)^n$ in the same way you assumed $(\sup S)^n < x$, because you assumed this as your hypothesis for contradiction. If you want to do that, you will have 6 different cases: For $(\sup S)^n < x$ and $(\sup S)^n > x$ you'd have to deal with $(\sup T)^n < x/(\sup S)^n$, $(\sup T)^n > x/(\sup S)^n$, and $(\sup T)^n = x/(\sup S)^n$. I would say, it's probably easier to prove this theorem by showing $(\sup S)^n \ge x$ and $(\sup S)^n \le x$.

Comment: The result you seek to prove is based on continuity of $x^n$ and whatever approach you take you will at some point need to prove that $|a^n-b^n|$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $|a-b|$ sufficiently small. So there is bound to be some approximation/estimation of $|a^n-b^n|$.